# Installing greenlet on Mac OS Catalina (10.15.7)

Tags: python, python-poetry

I would like to run a local copy of Python-based project on my Mac OS Catalina (10.15.7).
Project uses poetry as a Python-dependencies manager tool.
And while installing python dependencies it crashes on complying Greenlet package.

I have heard that such problems can be caused by the specifics of the Mac OS operating system.

What I have to od in order to properly install it?

```
<<MacBook-Pro-Gleb:project gleb$ poetry install
Installing dependencies from lock file

Package operations: 31 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

  • Installing greenlet (0.4.15): Failed

  EnvCommandError

  Command ['/Users/gleb/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/autobot-38lNXpzO-py3.9/bin/pip', 'install', '--no-deps', 'file:///Users/gleb/Library/Caches/pypoetry/artifacts/19/d6/61/d62a5b953b17327bddb648b63229019fb6f788679101a7ac2002936be3/greenlet-0.4.15.tar.gz'] errored with the following return code 1, and output: 
  Processing /Users/gleb/Library/Caches/pypoetry/artifacts/19/d6/61/d62a5b953b17327bddb648b63229019fb6f788679101a7ac2002936be3/greenlet-0.4.15.tar.gz
  Building wheels for collected packages: greenlet
    Building wheel for greenlet (setup.py): started
    Building wheel for greenlet (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/gleb/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/autobot-38lNXpzO-py3.9/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-req-build-a3ixiuh6/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-req-build-a3ixiuh6/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-wheel-3zoj_ptd
         cwd: /private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-req-build-a3ixiuh6/
    Complete output (21 lines):
    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'greenlet' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -I/Users/gleb/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/autobot-38lNXpzO-py3.9/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c greenlet.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/greenlet.o
    greenlet.c:823:13: warning: 'PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                            result = PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords(
                                     ^
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/ceval.h:17:1: note: 'PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    Py_DEPRECATED(3.9) PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords(
    ^
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
    #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                         ^
    greenlet.c:1046:4: error: use of undeclared identifier '_Py_DEC_REFTOTAL'
                            _Py_DEC_REFTOTAL;
                            ^
    1 warning and 1 error generated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for greenlet
    Running setup.py clean for greenlet
  Failed to build greenlet
  Installing collected packages: greenlet
      Running setup.py install for greenlet: started
      Running setup.py install for greenlet: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /Users/gleb/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/autobot-38lNXpzO-py3.9/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-req-build-a3ixiuh6/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-req-build-a3ixiuh6/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-record-h_bpfi00/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/gleb/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/autobot-38lNXpzO-py3.9/include/site/python3.9/greenlet
           cwd: /private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-req-build-a3ixiuh6/
      Complete output (21 lines):
      running install
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'greenlet' extension
      creating build
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9
      gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -I/Users/gleb/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/autobot-38lNXpzO-py3.9/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c greenlet.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/greenlet.o
      greenlet.c:823:13: warning: 'PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                              result = PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords(
                                       ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/ceval.h:17:1: note: 'PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
      Py_DEPRECATED(3.9) PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords(
      ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      greenlet.c:1046:4: error: use of undeclared identifier '_Py_DEC_REFTOTAL'
                              _Py_DEC_REFTOTAL;
                              ^
      1 warning and 1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/gleb/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/autobot-38lNXpzO-py3.9/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-req-build-a3ixiuh6/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-req-build-a3ixiuh6/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-record-h_bpfi00/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/gleb/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/autobot-38lNXpzO-py3.9/include/site/python3.9/greenlet Check the logs for full command output.
  

  at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/poetry/utils/env.py:1074 in _run
      1070│                 output = subprocess.check_output(
      1071│                     cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, **kwargs
      1072│                 )
      1073│         except CalledProcessError as e:
    → 1074│             raise EnvCommandError(e, input=input_)
      1075│ 
      1076│         return decode(output)
      1077│ 
      1078│     def execute(self, bin, *args, **kwargs):

MacBook-Pro-Gleb:autobot gleb$ poetry install
Installing dependencies from lock file

Package operations: 31 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

  • Installing greenlet (0.4.15): Failed

  EnvCommandError

  Command ['/Users/gleb/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/autobot-38lNXpzO-py3.9/bin/pip', 'install', '--no-deps', 'file:///Users/gleb/Library/Caches/pypoetry/artifacts/19/d6/61/d62a5b953b17327bddb648b63229019fb6f788679101a7ac2002936be3/greenlet-0.4.15.tar.gz'] errored with the following return code 1, and output: 
  Processing /Users/gleb/Library/Caches/pypoetry/artifacts/19/d6/61/d62a5b953b17327bddb648b63229019fb6f788679101a7ac2002936be3/greenlet-0.4.15.tar.gz
  Building wheels for collected packages: greenlet
    Building wheel for greenlet (setup.py): started
    Building wheel for greenlet (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/gleb/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/autobot-38lNXpzO-py3.9/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-req-build-9pzelg8a/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-req-build-9pzelg8a/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-wheel-oocl1xdw
         cwd: /private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-req-build-9pzelg8a/
    Complete output (21 lines):
    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'greenlet' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -I/Users/gleb/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/autobot-38lNXpzO-py3.9/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c greenlet.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/greenlet.o
    greenlet.c:823:13: warning: 'PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                            result = PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords(
                                     ^
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/ceval.h:17:1: note: 'PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    Py_DEPRECATED(3.9) PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords(
    ^
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
    #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                         ^
    greenlet.c:1046:4: error: use of undeclared identifier '_Py_DEC_REFTOTAL'
                            _Py_DEC_REFTOTAL;
                            ^
    1 warning and 1 error generated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for greenlet
    Running setup.py clean for greenlet
  Failed to build greenlet
  Installing collected packages: greenlet
      Running setup.py install for greenlet: started
      Running setup.py install for greenlet: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /Users/gleb/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/autobot-38lNXpzO-py3.9/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-req-build-9pzelg8a/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-req-build-9pzelg8a/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-record-olyg14c_/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/gleb/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/autobot-38lNXpzO-py3.9/include/site/python3.9/greenlet
           cwd: /private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-req-build-9pzelg8a/
      Complete output (21 lines):
      running install
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'greenlet' extension
      creating build
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9
      gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -I/Users/gleb/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/autobot-38lNXpzO-py3.9/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c greenlet.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/greenlet.o
      greenlet.c:823:13: warning: 'PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                              result = PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords(
                                       ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/ceval.h:17:1: note: 'PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
      Py_DEPRECATED(3.9) PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords(
      ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/pyport.h:508:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      greenlet.c:1046:4: error: use of undeclared identifier '_Py_DEC_REFTOTAL'
                              _Py_DEC_REFTOTAL;
                              ^
      1 warning and 1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/gleb/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/autobot-38lNXpzO-py3.9/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-req-build-9pzelg8a/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-req-build-9pzelg8a/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-record-olyg14c_/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/gleb/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/autobot-38lNXpzO-py3.9/include/site/python3.9/greenlet Check the logs for full command output.
  

  at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/poetry/utils/env.py:1074 in _run
      1070│                 output = subprocess.check_output(
      1071│                     cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, **kwargs
      1072│                 )
      1073│         except CalledProcessError as e:
    → 1074│             raise EnvCommandError(e, input=input_)
      1075│ 
      1076│         return decode(output)
      1077│ 
      1078│     def execute(self, bin, *args, **kwargs):
```

Comment: I think you should post the traceback, otherwise is impossible to check what's going on :D

Comment: You may want to read [ask].

Comment: @e.arbitrio, ok, just updated the post. please, check it

Comment: I think there are some issues with your python version + macosx. https://github.com/python-greenlet/greenlet/issues/181

BTW i'm able to install greenlet with macosx python 3.8.6 (pyenv) and poetry

Comment: @e.arbitrio, thank you! it works. but now I faced pillow failed to install. Do you have any suggestions on that?

Comment: @Gleb as before, to help with, we need details, and so i should see the error to understand the issue :/

Comment: @e.arbitrio, sure, sorry. I had to open [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66483842/cant-install-pillow-n-mac-os-catalina-10-15-7) to post the traceback. Please, check it there.