# Can't install pillow n Mac OS Catalina (10.15.7)

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library

I would like to run a local copy of Python-based project on my Mac OS Catalina (10.15.7). Project uses poetry as a Python-dependencies manager tool. And while installing python dependencies it crashes on complying pillow package.

Earlier I had [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66459307/installing-greenlet-on-mac-os-catalina-10-15-7) with installing greenlet package, but changing global python version from 3.9.1 to 3.8.6 (peenv) on my Mac resolved the issue

What I have to od in order to properly install pillow package?

```
gleb@MacBook-Pro-Gleb projectname % poetry install
Installing dependencies from lock file

Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals

  • Installing pillow (5.4.1): Failed

  EnvCommandError

  Command ['/Users/gleb/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/projectname-38lNXpzO-py3.8/bin/pip', 'install', '--no-deps', 'file:///Users/gleb/Library/Caches/pypoetry/artifacts/80/ad/91/3913b9a46f97fe5d27106af6465d0c7445ba1bc414f6344c24141ce1d3/Pillow-5.4.1.tar.gz'] errored with the following return code 1, and output: 
  Processing /Users/gleb/Library/Caches/pypoetry/artifacts/80/ad/91/3913b9a46f97fe5d27106af6465d0c7445ba1bc414f6344c24141ce1d3/Pillow-5.4.1.tar.gz
  Building wheels for collected packages: Pillow
    Building wheel for Pillow (setup.py): started
    Building wheel for Pillow (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/gleb/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/autobot-38lNXpzO-py3.8/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-req-build-i4zvjn4e/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-req-build-i4zvjn4e/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-wheel-nezbz82h
         cwd: /private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-req-build-i4zvjn4e/
    Complete output (174 lines):
    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PdfParser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/features.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_tkinter_finder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageMorph.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BlpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/OleFileIO.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/DdsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PyAccess.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    copying src/PIL/FtexImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
    running egg_info
    writing src/Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src/Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to src/Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching '*.c'
    warning: no files found matching '*.h'
    warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_static'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.codecov.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yaml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis/*'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    writing manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    
    
    The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
    
    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-req-build-i4zvjn4e/setup.py", line 765, in <module>
        setup(name=NAME,
      File "/Users/gleb/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/autobot-38lNXpzO-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/Users/gleb/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/Users/gleb/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/Users/gleb/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Users/gleb/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/autobot-38lNXpzO-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/Users/gleb/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/Users/gleb/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Users/gleb/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/Users/gleb/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/Users/gleb/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Users/gleb/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "/private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-req-build-i4zvjn4e/setup.py", line 612, in build_extensions
        raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException: zlib
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-req-build-i4zvjn4e/setup.py", line 812, in <module>
        raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException:
    
    The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
    
    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
    
    
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for Pillow
    Running setup.py clean for Pillow
  Failed to build Pillow
  Installing collected packages: Pillow
      Running setup.py install for Pillow: started
      Running setup.py install for Pillow: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /Users/gleb/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/autobot-38lNXpzO-py3.8/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-req-build-i4zvjn4e/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-req-build-i4zvjn4e/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-record-uy92t_94/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/gleb/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/autobot-38lNXpzO-py3.8/include/site/python3.8/Pillow
           cwd: /private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-req-build-i4zvjn4e/
      Complete output (176 lines):
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PdfParser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/features.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/_tkinter_finder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageMorph.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/BlpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/OleFileIO.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/DdsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PyAccess.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      copying src/PIL/FtexImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.8/PIL
      running egg_info
      writing src/Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src/Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to src/Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching '*.c'
      warning: no files found matching '*.h'
      warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_static'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.codecov.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yaml'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis/*'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
      writing manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      running build_ext
      
      
      The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
      a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
      
      Please see the install instructions at:
         https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
      
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-req-build-i4zvjn4e/setup.py", line 765, in <module>
          setup(name=NAME,
        File "/Users/gleb/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/autobot-38lNXpzO-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "/Users/gleb/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/Users/gleb/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/Users/gleb/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/Users/gleb/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/autobot-38lNXpzO-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
          return orig.install.run(self)
        File "/Users/gleb/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/install.py", line 545, in run
          self.run_command('build')
        File "/Users/gleb/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/Users/gleb/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/Users/gleb/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "/Users/gleb/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/Users/gleb/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/Users/gleb/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
          self.build_extensions()
        File "/private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-req-build-i4zvjn4e/setup.py", line 612, in build_extensions
          raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
      __main__.RequiredDependencyException: zlib
      
      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
      
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-req-build-i4zvjn4e/setup.py", line 812, in <module>
          raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
      __main__.RequiredDependencyException:
      
      The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
      a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
      
      Please see the install instructions at:
         https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
      
      
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/gleb/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/autobot-38lNXpzO-py3.8/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-req-build-i4zvjn4e/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-req-build-i4zvjn4e/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/jx/6pdyz9ds1yq9_79yz1pv0g440000gn/T/pip-record-uy92t_94/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/gleb/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/autobot-38lNXpzO-py3.8/include/site/python3.8/Pillow Check the logs for full command output.
  

  at ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/utils/env.py:1074 in _run
      1070│                 output = subprocess.check_output(
      1071│                     cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, **kwargs
      1072│                 )
      1073│         except CalledProcessError as e:
    → 1074│             raise EnvCommandError(e, input=input_)
      1075│ 
      1076│         return decode(output)
      1077│ 
      1078│     def execute(self, bin, *args, **kwargs):
```

Comment: Have you checked what the error says: "*The headers or library files could not be found for zlib, a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.  Please see the install instructions at: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html*"

Comment: It would help people reproduce the problem if you shared a sample of your pyproject.toml, at least the parts that include Pillow. Because `python3 -m pip install Pillow` works ok on my macOS 10.15.7 and Python 3.8.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you missed a system dependency: `zlib`. I would install it via homebrew:

`brew install zlib`

Comment: It worked for me, with the following piece of advice given by the brew command :

For compilers to find zlib you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include"

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

You are trying to install Pillow 5.4.1 on Python 3.8.

From the support table at https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html we can see Pillow 5.4.1 does not support Python 3.8, because that Pillow version was released before Python 3.8 came out, which means there are no precompiled binary wheels and it's attempting to compile from source.

This error message appears several times in the log and tells you what to do:

> The headers or library files could not be found for zlib, a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source. Please see the install instructions at: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Better yet, install at least Pillow 6.2.1 for Python 3.8 and it will use the precompiled wheel. It will be faster too.

(I recommend using the latest 8.1.1 as it fixes a number of CVEs.)